React-native, fetch crushes all my js functions after await and don't call it after request
I have that code
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  console.log('Render');

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Before');

    fetch('https://google.com/').then(res => {
      console.log('Test');
      console.log('res', res);
    });

    console.log('After');
  }, []);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        padding: 64,
      }}
    >
      <Text>Test2</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

And my log console don't show anything... No logs, no hot reload...
But if i check flipper for network requests - it looks fine, what can i do, to fix it?
That problem occurs when i try to modify my tests (jest). After that - all my fetch functions doesn't call a "then" or "await". Also axios do the same.
When i checkout back (before changes) - it doesn't work. BUT!!! if i clone my project again, checkout back (before changes), then npm i && cd ios && pod install && cd .. && npm run ios - that will be work fine.
But when i switch back to branch with fixes - problem occurs and checkout back does nothing
Ask me for another files which u need to read, cuz project is under NDA, and i can't reproduce this behavior on a simple project

*babel.config.js*


module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', "@babel/preset-typescript", '@babel/preset-react'],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
      {
        legacy: true,
      },
    ],
    'module:react-native-dotenv',
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
  ],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: ['transform-remove-console'],
    },
  },
};

Problem was in line "'@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',"
I'm just commented this line, full clean and rebuild and fetch start work.
